# jQuery knob - Rendering issues

Tags: jquery, angular-directive, jquery-knob, round-slider

I'm trying to use a jquery knob in angular, and i've created a directive in order to use it.

Now, i've seen many jquery knob examples, and in most of them, there's the current value displayed in the centre of the dial...but not in my case!
And also, how do i set the numbers to be WITHOUT DECIMALS?

Here's my html and angular directive code:

**HTML**

```
<knob ng-model="temp" value="0"></knob>
<input type="text" ng-model="temp">
```

**knob.js**

```
angular.module('knob', [])
    .directive('knob', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                element.knob({
                    min: attrs.min,
                    max: attrs.max,
                    thickness: .2,
                    step: .5,
                    angleOffset: -125,
                    displayInput: true,
                    angleArc: 250,
                    change: function (value) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                        });
                    }
                });
                ngModel.$render = function () {
                    element.val(ngModel.$viewValue).trigger("change");
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

Here's how it looks on the browser:

[image]

And here how i'd like it to be (not talking about the color, but about the value displayed as INT in the middle)

[image]

Many thanks in advance

**EDIT**

As suggested, i replaced jquery knob with roundSlider, but i have a couple of issue that can be found here:
http://jsbin.com/doketasuju/edit?html,output

1) Why do i have white background in a "diamond shape" style that i don't want?

2) If i type something in the input, it's not working!

This is an example on how i'm going to use it, but i need to fix this couple of issues first.
Thanks

**EDIT 2**

Something like this to add labels:

[image]

And it should obviously display min and max values from the slider attributes

Comment: The problem is due to, the knob should rendered by input element (which displayed in center).. But here the "knob" tag was used (custom tag for directive).. so need to change the binding based on this.. Are you need the solution with knob or you can compatible with any other plugin ?

Comment: Any circular slider will do

Comment: Is the below answer helps you or you need any other functionality ?

Comment: No not really...i used this plugin before, and then i changed to knob. I know that knob should work in angular, as seen in this video example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz8lAKHBgJY. I'm doing the same thing as he does, but i have decimals and he has not and i cannot figure out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For EDIT 2:

Currently there is no inbuilt option for label support. But you can achieve that functionality by using the internal code. Check the below demo:

### http://jsbin.com/gazara/1/edit?html,output

Here by adjusting the margin values for `.num1 span` and `.num2 span` classes you can position the label.

Demo with half slider: http://jsbin.com/tamumo/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved your requirement with [**jQuery roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin.

It supports the angular binding by inbuilt, so no need to create the custom directive externally for this.

Please check the demo from here:

### http://jsbin.com/yoboruquvo/edit?html,output

For more details about **roundSlider** check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Hope it helps you ...

### Edit

1) By setting the slider bg color corresponding to the background you can solve this.

`.rs-bg-color {
   background: gray;
}`

2) Solved the issue while using the directive.

### Updated Demo: http://jsbin.com/puwefi/edit?html,output

Comment: Ok, i'm going to use your example. I cannot spend a lot of time on this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, i have a couple of issues with your example...please see my edited question.

Comment: You are the best! thanks a lot for all your patience and help!

Comment: Last quick question, i checked the documentation but i wasn't able to find it...do you know if there's an option that allows you to add labels (like 0 at the start of the circle and 100 at the end)? Or do i have to do it myself? thanks

Comment: label means, are you need to add the number outside the circle ah ?